# What and how to do when using loop to get data from database to load in the gridview?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have this system where user can select the items in the `AspxListBox`, then they click the button below that will `run a SQL` to get the data from database by the items value. Then, all the data will load into the `aspxgridview`.

The list can be more than one or two. User can select either one or more than one. Once they select, they will click the `Add` button . However when I select two or more items in it, they only get the data from the last item value. Here is my code :

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

Dim dt As New Datatable
Dim myconn As New clsConnection

For Each item As ListEditItem In lBoxItem.Items
    If item.Selected = True Then
        Dim strItem As String = ""
        strItem += item.Text
        
        Dim StrSelect as String = "SELECT ID, Description, Qty, Remark FROM table_1 WHERE itemString = @ItemString"
    myconn.AddParameter("@ItemString", MySqlDbType.String)
        myconn.SetParameter("@ItemString", strItem)
        
    Try
            myconn.OpenConnection()
            myconn.FillDataTable(dt, strSelect)
            myconn.CloseConnection()
            myconn.ClearAllParameter()
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        grdViewItems.DataSource = dt
        grdViewItems.DataBind()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            myconn.CloseConnection()
            myconn.ClearAllParameter()
        End Try
        
    End If
    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are setting the DataSource on each iteration of the loop, which means you will only get the last added to the grid. You can use the loop to build the SQL statement and add all the parameters, and then run the statement after the loop.  That way you'll have all the data.

Comment: you mean , use loop in my SQL statement ? can you show me the way, please ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill a new datatable in each loop, only the last one is kept. You must merge each of theses dt in a global one and bind it to you datagridView :

code looks like that :

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable 'global
    Dim myconn As New clsConnection

'initialize dt schema
    Dim ID As New DataColumn("ID", GetType(System.Int32))
    Dim Description As New DataColumn("Description", GetType(System.String))
    Dim Qty As New DataColumn("Qty", GetType(System.Int32))
    Dim Remark As New DataColumn("Remark", GetType(System.String))
    
    dt.Columns.Add(Description)
    dt.Columns.Add(Qty)
    dt.Columns.Add(Remark)
    dt.Columns.Add(ID)

    ' Set the primary key column.
    dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ID}
'end initialize dt

For Each item As ListEditItem In lBoxItem.Items
    If item.Selected = True Then
    Dim strItem As String = ""
    strItem += item.Text
    
    Dim StrSelect As String = "SELECT ID, Description, Qty, Remark FROM table_1 WHERE itemString = @ItemString"
    myconn.AddParameter("@ItemString", MySqlDbType.String)
    myconn.SetParameter("@ItemString", strItem)
        Try
            Dim dtl As New DataTable 'local
            myconn.OpenConnection()
            myconn.FillDataTable(dtl, StrSelect)
        
            'other methode to inialize dt
            If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                dt = dtl.Clone
            End If
            'end initialize 
            
            myconn.CloseConnection()
            myconn.ClearAllParameter()
            If dtl.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'add dtl to dt
                dt.Merge(dtl, False)
            End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            myconn.CloseConnection()
            myconn.ClearAllParameter()
        End Try
    End If
    
Next
    
    grdViewItems.DataSource = dt
    grdViewItems.DataBind()
    
End Sub
```

dtl is created in each loop.

dt is global and is the "sum" of each dtl using  `dt.Merge(dtl, False)`

dt must be initialized with same colums schema as dtl (2 methods, choose one)

Comment: i used this merge methos and it works for me ! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend only hitting the database once, as multiple hits can slow it down which impacts the user experience.

Here's an example using SqlClient. I see you're using MySql, so you'd have to alter it slightly. As they all use the same interfaces it's probably just changing the type names e.g. change SqlConnection to MySqlConnection. I'm also not using your clsConnection object.

```
Private Function GetData(items As String()) As DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim command = conn.CreateCommand()
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim paramID As Integer = 0
        Dim paramNames As New List(Of String)
        For Each item In items
            paramID += 1
            Dim name = $"@_param{paramID}"
            paramNames.Add(name)
            command.Parameters.Add(name, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = item
        Next
        command.CommandText = $"SELECT ID, Description, Qty, Remark FROM table_1 WHERE itemString IN ( {String.Join(",", paramNames)})"
        Dim adapater As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter() With {.SelectCommand = command}
        table.Locale = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        conn.Open()
        adapater.Fill(table)
        Return table
    End Using
End Function
```

To call the method use:

```
grdViewItems.DataSource = GetData(lBoxItem.Items)
```

This assumes *lBoxItem.Items* are strings. If not then cast them first into an array. Also note that the SqlConnection is wrapped in a using statement, where the connection will close automatically. Also I've put the Try/Catch further up the hierarchy, as it will throw to that. That's a personal preference.

If you need to use your clsConnection object, then I would move the method into that class, and add the sql string as a parameter.